# AS3 RTMP broadcasting feed doesn't include audio

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, rtmp

I'm developing a little ActionScript3 app that broadcast the camera and microphone of the user to a RTMP feed.

The video is working great but the microphone doesn't work.
Playing the RTMP feed with VLC indicate that there is not audio feed at all, only the video feed.

The server (Wowza) is currently used with others streams so the problem is not coming from here. There was also a flash broadcast app used on the server before that was working fine.

Here's the code:

```
// Connection code

// Code run after connected event on connection

var h264:H264VideoStreamSettings = new H264VideoStreamSettings();
h264.setProfileLevel(H264Profile.BASELINE, H264Level.LEVEL_3_1);

outStream = new NetStream(connection);
outStream.videoStreamSettings = h264;

// Camera code

microphone = Microphone.getEnhancedMicrophone(0);

if( microphone )
{
    var options:MicrophoneEnhancedOptions = new MicrophoneEnhancedOptions();
    options.mode = MicrophoneEnhancedMode.FULL_DUPLEX;
    microphone.enhancedOptions = options;
    microphone.setLoopBack(false);
    microphone.setUseEchoSuppression(true);
    microphone.setSilenceLevel(0);
    microphone.codec = SoundCodec.SPEEX;
    microphone.encodeQuality = 10;
    microphone.rate = 16;
    microphone.gain = 75;

    outStream.attachAudio(microphone);
}

outStream.publish( streamKey );
```

Comment: What happens if you tell Wowza to send out **[H.264 with AAC](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?347-How-to-convert-Flash-Player-11-output-from-H-264-Speex-audio-to-H-264-AAC-audio-using-Wowza-Transcoder#comments)**? Does VLC now play it?

Comment: Do you get the same results using Microphone.getMicrophone? Is the first microphone that flash is detecting the microphone you're trying to use? How's your hardware? In your system's sound properties is your microphone being detected and handled ok?

Comment: Also try using `if ( microphone != -1 )` as your `IF` statement with an `else { trace ("microphone not detected"); }`

Comment: I tried putting a `trace('mic detected')` after the `outStream.attachAudio` and it's working fine. Also if I set the LoopBack to true, I hear the microphone so the problem is not coming from here I think.
For Wowza, it's working fine with another Flash Broadcast app, so I don't think it's coming from here either.

Comment: have you tried not using echo suppression/enhanced mode? Or using Nellymoser instead of SPEEX?   Start with the basics and see if that works:  `outStream.attachAudio(Microphone.getMicrophone())`;